# WPF - Use a vector XAML file

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I've got a series of vector XAML files (from Icon Experience). How can I use them in another window? I've tried adding them to app.xaml as a resource dictionary, but I get the error 'An error occurred while finding the resource dictionary'

Example XAML Vector

```
<Viewbox xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" Width="128" Height="128">
<Canvas Width="10240" Height="10240">
    <Path Data="M6400 7527l0 -2330 -3620 3621c-125,124 -328,124 -453,0l-905 -905c-124,-125 -124,-328 0,-453l3621 -3620 -2329 0c-67,0 -123,-38 -148,-99 -26,-61 -12,-128 34,-174l1460 -1460c124,-124 276,-187 452,-187l3488 0c176,0 320,144 320,320l0 3488c0,176 -63,328 -187,452l-1460 1460c-46,46 -113,60 -174,34 -61,-25 -99,-81 -99,-147z" Fill="#252525"/>
</Canvas>
```

My attempt to add them in app.xaml

```
<ResourceDictionary x:Name="arrowIE" Source="Assets/arrow_up_right/xaml"/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do it like this:

1. Create a Resource Dictionary (right-click project node in Solution Explorer and choose **Add** > **Resource Dictionary**):

   ```
   <ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                   xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                   xmlns:local="clr-namespace:DuplicateFinder.Views">
       <PathGeometry x:Key="UpArrow" Figures="M6400 7527l0 -2330 -3620 3621c-125,124 -328,124 -453,0l-905 -905c-124,-125 -124,-328 0,-453l3621 -3620 -2329 0c-67,0 -123,-38 -148,-99 -26,-61 -12,-128 34,-174l1460 -1460c124,-124 276,-187 452,-187l3488 0c176,0 320,144 320,320l0 3488c0,176 -63,328 -187,452l-1460 1460c-46,46 -113,60 -174,34 -61,-25 -99,-81 -99,-147z" />
   </ResourceDictionary>
   ```
2. Include your Resource Dictionary in your main Window (or UserControl):

   ```
   <Window.Resources>
     <ResourceDictionary>
       <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
         <ResourceDictionary Source="Dictionary1.xaml" />
       </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>

       <!--Place other resources here-->
     </ResourceDictionary>
   </Window.Resources>
   ```
3. Use your icons data in a Path object. Use `ViewBox` to fit them inside the available space:

   ```
   <Viewbox Stretch="Uniform">
     <Path Data="{StaticResource UpArrow}" Fill="Black" Stroke="Black" />
   </Viewbox>
   ```

Comment: This worked for me, only difference I made was adding the resource dictionary to the app.xaml <Application.Resources>, rather than window resources. Thanks